# Excel VBA の1回の実行で、通過した通過しなかったfunction、subを分類する方法を教えて下さい

Tags: アルゴリズム, vba, awk, graphviz

1. 全てのfunction, subに一行ずつ `debug.print”function1通過”` と書く方法しかありませんか？
2. 書くとしたら、正規表現置き換えの方法で、対応可能ですか？
   全エクスポートで、エディタの正規表現置換後、全インポートを予定しています。
   例) 全てのfunction, sub2行目に `debug.print "なまえ通過”` を挿入する方法がありますか?
3. 他言語でも、アドバイスをいただけると、助かります。

よろしくお願いします。

```
Sub Auto_Open()
call aa
end sub
sub aa
end sub
sub bb
end sub
```

- 通過したsubはAuto_Openとaa
- 通過しなかったsubはbb

Comment: VBA は詳しくありませんが、少なくとも `call` されていなければその `sub` は呼ばれない、になりませんか？

Comment: そうですね。`call`文も、全文一度に`コメントにしたcall`文に変換できると助かります。方法として、全`call`文の名前を、ストックして、変換かける事できますか？実行してエラーを発生させて、一行ずつ`call`文コメントアウトを想定していました。

Comment: function文について、いい方法があれば、教えて下さい。

Comment: Callを使わなくてもSubやFunctionは呼び出せます。静的に(コードを実行せずに)呼び出し有無を判定するにはコードの構文解析が必要になり、実現するのは難しいと思います。ログを埋め込むなどして、動的に(コードを実行して)判定する方法が現実的だと思います。

Comment: subとfunctionの中にdebugプリントを入れるのが

Comment: 構文解析。graphvizの専門家のアドバイスを聞きたいので、タグ追加しました。

Comment: 直接関連は無いですが、こんなツール類があるようです。[rixatron/vbacop](https://github.com/rixatron/vbacop), [\[MS-VBAL\]: VBA Language Specification](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/microsoft_general_purpose_programming_languages/ms-vbal/), [Free Add-In to profile VBA speed and coverage](https://sysmod.wordpress.com/2017/03/09/free-add-in-to-profile-vba-speed-and-coverage/), [VBA-tools](https://github.com/VBA-tools), [AccUnit](https://accunit.access-codelib.net/), [RubberDuck](https://rubberduckvba.com/), [VBA開発環境をモダンにする...](https://qiita.com/mochimo/items/e9be36619a76e15bc898)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fumu 7さんの回答の実装例です。
awkを使っています。WSLで確認しました。
引数で指定したbasファイルのSubとFunctionの定義の後にdebug.printを埋め込みます。変換結果は元のファイルの先頭にDebug_を付加したファイルに書き込みます。
書き込む内容はファイル名、行番号、定義の行です。
※プロパティのアクセサは対象としていません。

【debug.print埋め込みスクリプト】

```
#!/bin/sh
conv_bas(){
    file=$1
    awk '{
        print $0
    }
    /^Sub/||/^Function/{
        sub(/\r/,"")
        printf("    debug.print(\"%s:%s:%s\")\r\n", FILENAME, FNR, $0);
    }
    ' ${file}
}
for file in $@
do
    conv_bas ${file} > Debug_${file}
done
```

【実行例(抜粋)】

```
Module11.bas:203:Function Left2Pos(left As Integer, width As Integer) As Integer
Module11.bas:203:Function Left2Pos(left As Integer, width As Integer) As Integer
Module11.bas:203:Function Left2Pos(left As Integer, width As Integer) As Integer
Module11.bas:200:Function Pos2Left(pos As Integer, width As Integer) As Integer
Module11.bas:203:Function Left2Pos(left As Integer, width As Integer) As Integer
Module11.bas:200:Function Pos2Left(pos As Integer, width As Integer) As Integer
Module11.bas:203:Function Left2Pos(left As Integer, width As Integer) As Integer
　　　以下略
```

---

このままでは集計が面倒です。
呼び出し時に回数カウントし、集計結果を表示するデバッグ用のモジュールを作ってみました。

【集計モジュール】

```
Option Explicit
Dim debugCallCount As Object
Sub DebugStartCallCont()
    Set debugCallCount = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End Sub
Sub DebugRecordCallCont(Msg As String)
    debugCallCount(Msg) = debugCallCount(Msg) + 1
    
End Sub
Sub DebugPrintCallCont()
    Dim var As Variant
    Debug.Print ("==========================")
    Debug.Print ("Count:File:Line:Definition")
    Debug.Print ("==========================")
    
    For Each var In debugCallCount
        Debug.Print (debugCallCount.Item(var) & ":" & var)
    Next var
    Debug.Print ("==========================")
End Sub
```

【使い方】

集計を開始する処理の先頭に次のコードを記述します。

```
Call DebugStartCallCont
```

集計結果を表示したい箇所で次のコードを記述します。

```
Call DebugPrintCallCont
```

プロシジャの定義の後にDebugRecordCallContを記述します。
以下のスクリプトで埋め込むのが簡単です。
【DebugRecordCallCont埋め込みスクリプト】

```
#!/bin/sh
conv_bas(){
    file=$1
    awk '{
        print $0
    }
    /^Sub/||/^Function/{
        sub(/\r/,"")
        printf("    DebugRecordCallCont (\"%s:%s:%s\")\r\n", FILENAME, FNR, $0);
    }
    ' ${file}
}
for file in $@
do
    conv_bas ${file} > Debug_${file}
done
```

【実行例】

```
==========================
Count:File:Line:Definition
==========================
1:Module11.bas:314:Sub MakeDiagram()
1:Module11.bas:525:Sub Initialize()
4:Module11.bas:531:Function RefOpt(name As String) As Variant
10:Module11.bas:94:Sub RmSheet(xls As String, nm As String)
16:Module11.bas:84:Function IsSheetExist(nm As String)
6:Module11.bas:105:Sub AddWorkSheet(xls As String, nm As String)
1:Module11.bas:500:Sub RmDiaShapes()
1:Module11.bas:492:Sub RmShapes(nm As String)
86:Module11.bas:148:Function ObjectProp(id As String) As TObject
4:Module11.bas:265:Function CreateShape(sheet As Worksheet, fig_sheet As Worksheet, shape As String, id As String, pos As Integer, top As Integer) As String
44:Module11.bas:165:Function FigProp(id As String) As TFig
21:Module11.bas:197:Function GetBoxHeight(Title As String) As String
21:Module11.bas:192:Function GetBoxWidth(Title As String) As String
65:Module11.bas:200:Function Pos2Left(pos As Integer, width As Integer) As Integer
20:Module11.bas:301:Function CreateCustomConnector(sheet As Worksheet, fig_sheet As Worksheet, beginObj As String, endObj As String)
17:Module11.bas:251:Function CreateText(sheet As Worksheet, id As String, pos As Integer, top As Integer) As String
55:Module11.bas:212:Function Name2No(ws As Worksheet, nm As String) As Integer
7:Module11.bas:237:Function GetTopBrotherNo(nm As String) As Integer
7:Module11.bas:224:Function GetParentNo(nm As String) As Integer
58:Module11.bas:203:Function Left2Pos(left As Integer, width As Integer) As Integer
=====================
```

Answer (score 1):

すべてのsubとfunctionの中にdebug.printを入れる以外にないと思います。

VBAのプログラム（Module)は、"ファイルのエクスポート"でテキストファイル(拡張子は".bas")に保存できますから、テキストファイルの中にdebug.printを挿入してゆけばいいでしょう。

だいたいの手順は、

・修正したいVBAプログラムのファイルを開く。（ファイルA)
・修正したVBAプログラムを入れるファイルを生成する。　（ファイルB)

そして、以下の操作をファイルAのすべてのデータを読み終わるまで繰り返す。
　　・ファイルAから１行読み出して、そこに"Sub"か"Function")が含まれていれば、
　　　　・ファイルAから読み出した行と、debug.printの行をファイルBに追加する
　　・"Sub"も"Function”も含まれていなければ、
　　　　・ファイルAから読み出した行を、そのままファイルBに追加する

・ファイルBを閉じる。
・ファイルのインポートで、ファイルBを読み込む。

＝＝＝
プログラムはVBAに固執しないで、Pythonとか、テキストエディタのマクロ機能とか、使い慣れたもの・使いやすいものでやってください。

正規表現に精通されているのでは、正規表現でもかまわないと思います。